# A bike is sold by an automobile agency for rupess $19200$ cash or for $ 4800$ cash downpayment

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem

**Problem  :**  A bike is sold by an automobile agency for rupess $19200$ cash or for $ 4800$ cash downpayment together with $5$ equal monthly installment if rate of interest charged by the company is $12%$ per annum .find the amount of the installment

**solution:**  amount after downpayment $= 14400$

simple interest= $720$

Amount $= 14400+720$

= $15120$

installment =$3024$

Am I right ??

Comment: interest changes with time...

Comment: It increases with increase in time...

Comment: The $720$ are the interest for $14400$ during $5$ months. 
However, at the end of the first month you do not owe the bank $14400$ anymore.  Thus, this may not be correct, but it may also be the intended solution.

Comment: Did the answer help ?

Answer (score 1):

**Some hints:**

- The monthly interest rate is $i_m=\frac{i}{12}=0.01$
- The future value of the five installments is

  $$\sum_{k=0}^4 x\cdot  (1+i\cdot k) =(5+10\cdot i)\cdot x=5.1x$$
- The future value of $19,200$ cash and $4,800$ cash  are
  $ 19,200\cdot (1+0.01\cdot 5)$ and $4,800\cdot (1+0.01\cdot
     5)$ respectively.
- The future value of the five installments and $4,800$ has to be
  equal to the future value of $19,200$.